# Javascript [jQuery] filter array by key and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filtering

I need to filter an array if a key meets a certain value, for example:

```
data = theArray;
var theColumn = "thc012";
var theVal = 4;
data = $.filter(data, theColumn, theVal );
```

And then the result would be all the array items that match `theColumn = theVal ;`

I am already using the jQuery Library so if any jQuery functions help, use them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript objects are key-value pairs. You can use them.
Like so:

```
var data = {
    "cars": ["Honda", "Toyota", "Subaru"],
    "planes": ["Boeing", "Airbus", "Mig"]
};
var key = "cars";
data[key]; // All cars
key = "planes";
data[key]; // All planes
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `grep` method: [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

Then just supply it with a function that checks if `theColumn = theKey;`

Comment: Ok, that looks like it works great, however I am passing my data dynamically, so for example the `key` is set in a variable. This means it I do `el.theColumn`, with `theColumn` being the variable with the key name, and `el`, being the array, it in fact looks for the key name `theColumn`, instead of what the value of the variable `theColumn` is, if this makes sense?

Comment: I don't think I understand. Can you give an example with actual values?

Answer (score 0):

if i have understood your question correctly this should do it

```
 $.each(data,function(row,key){ 
    if(key != theKey && theColumn != theColumn){
        delete data[key];
    } 
 });
```